# Is it possible to export a database without its Users?

Tags: sql-server, database-backup

Is it possible to export a SQL Server database (data, structures) without its users ?

If yes, is it possible using SSMS ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way to get the result you're after but it's **not** a backup and should not be considered as such (see [gbn's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/320064/is-it-possible-to-backup-a-database-without-its-users/320067#320067) to understand why).

This is a handy tool for generating scripts that you might use in an application installer and to prime your application's database with objects such as stored procedures, views reference tables and data. But it's **not** to be used as a mission critical backup.

`Tasks -> Generate Scripts` provides the capability to script your database and data and choose which objects to ignore (for example users):

[image]

On the second page you can choose what to script:

[image]

Just make use "Users" is not selected.

On the next page select the `Advanced` button to open the Advanced Scripting Options window:

[image]

The Advanced Scripting Options window allows you to pick and choose what to script and how to script it. If you want to script the data as well as the schema then choose `Schema and Data` in the "Types of data to script" option:

[image]

Again and just to re-iterate, this is **not** considered a reliable or sanctioned method to backup a database.

Comment: Note: this isn't a coherent, restorable, point in time snapshot of the database.

Comment: @gbn - OP just clarified that this is just an export and not treating as backup.

Answer (score 2):

No. Users can:

- have permissions
- be memebers of roles
- own schemas and objects

If users were stripped out you break the database

If you want to export all data and scripts then you can skip users that way. 
But this isn't a backup

Comment: You are right. I meant an export.